# A user has received the 'Editor' badge multiple times in the last 24 hours

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I stumbled on a user that had **1 reputation point** and **17 bronze badges**.

I looked at his badges and found out that he has been awarded the badge **`[Editor]`** **7 times**.

[image]

Then clicking on the badge I get the badge's history:

[image]

Isn't this badge awarded only once? Also, it seems the post he edited was deleted. Isn't his badge supposed to be removed from the list?

I figured out that this was a bug of some sort. This might be resolved at the end of the day when the script checks for irregularities...

Comment: it could be a bug? first edit being "1" on the "edited" stat, if they keep getting deleted they go back to 0 then back to 1 etc. Maybe this is exploiting?

Comment: This is not an exploit, the time-stamps on the badges are not correlated with anything the user did.  He also got 6 Custodian badges, but no review is visible.  This must be the machine screwing up.

Comment: alright let's get the pencil and paper back. my local post office should be easy to find just google tha- oh

Comment: Do note that the only badges that can/will be removed, barring manually by the staff in incredibly special circumstances, are tag badges. The rest of them, Editor included, stay even if you no longer deserve it.

Comment: The only way to review suggested edits at that rep is on your own posts... Possibly an account merge gone wrong? Suggesting an edit from one account and reviewing the suggested edit on the other account nets you an editor badge on one and a custodian badge on the other. Merge the two and you have both. That's all I've got, will need moderator powers to know more I reckon.

Comment: Could be related to the bug I reported on Meta.SE a few days ago: [Was my answer really twice as good? (doubled "Good Answer" badge)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/311662). There was no account merge, just one suggested edit, no repeated deleting and undeleting (the post was deleted just once) and only 3 revisions by the OP on a single post. This is the badge system going screwy.

Comment: I'd like more badges, just saying

Comment: @TheGeneral is this you? https://i.imgur.com/2eUIuDC.png

Comment: Also, 6 Custodian badges for a 1-reputation user isn't normal since the badge is awarded once per review type. A 1-reputation user only has enough reputation to review suggested edits on their own posts, so they can't have reviewed stuff in 6 different queues. Besides, [this specific user hasn't reviewed anything at all](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9996009/kaspianr?tab=activity&sort=reviews), so they shouldn't have any Custodian badge at all.

Comment: Is there a query on [Data Stack Exchange](http://data.stackexchange.com) that could show all members who have the badge **[Editor]** multiple times?

Answer (score 4):

Well... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

As much as I'd love to be able to write a decent answer here describing what happened, there's no way to reliably reconstruct that given how much time has passed. On the upside, it appears that whatever the issue was... it's been fixed and the badge counts are correct now.

Thanks for the report! If this happens again, please post a new one.